# Extract city names from strings with ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Is there a way to extract city names from strings? E.g.:

```
"I'm going to New York then to Berlin"
# => ["New York", "Berlin"]
```

Comment: please publish what you tried and also a sample of the strings and citynames

Comment: The only way to extract city names, is for you to have a reference list of possible city names, and then use a quick search through the words of the string, looking for known cities. There is nothing about a word that defines it as a city name, so you have to go at it the other way around, starting from what you know are cities and look in the string for them.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
regex = /New York|Berlin|Amsterdam|Tokyo|Paris|London/
"I'm going to New York then to Berlin".scan(regex) #=> ["New York", "Berlin"]
```

Please improve your question if this is not what you meant.

Comment: Does this mean that I must enter all cities in `regex = /New York|Berlin|Amsterdam|Tokyo|Paris|London/`?

Comment: @nadine1988: Yes. The Problem is, there is really no way to just know what a city name is, because the only special thing about them is that they are capitalized. And capitalization is also names, months, weekdays, etc. You need a list of cities, or this can't be done.

Comment: This approach is better: [https://github.com/mblongii/ruby-ner](https://github.com/mblongii/ruby-ner)

Can I apply for a string, and not just for a URL?

Comment: From a quick glance at "ruby-ner", it's just a proof they can connect to, and retrieve the contents of, the "Stanford Named Entity Recognizer". You'd need to write code to take the returned results of the same sort of connection and turn it into something you can use when searching your strings, again, pointing to the need to create a regex.

Answer (score 2):

You need a list of city names, which can be a huge list, with multiple variations of spelling and many duplicates.

Once you have the list you want, this will return a usable regular expression you can use to scan strings, returning the cities found in your list:

```
cities = [
  'Albuquerque',
  'Alexandria',
  'Jackson',
  'Ammansland',
  'Darby',
  'Atkins Bank',
  'Kingston',
  'Kinston',
  'Caswell',
  'Kinston',
  'Awiehawken',
  'Weehawken',
  'Bergen',
  'Jersey City',
  'Berlin',
  'Marne',
  'Beverwijck',
  'Albany',
  'Breuckelen',
  'Brooklyn',
  'New York',
  'Campbellton',
  'Cross Creek',
  'Fayetteville',
  'Chamassungh',
  'Finlandia',
  'Marcus Hook',
  'Charleston',
  'St. Charles',
].uniq(&:downcase).sort_by(&:downcase)

regex = /\b#{ Regexp.union(cities) }\b/i
```

The regex built looks like:

```
puts regex.source

# => \b(?-mix:Albany|Albuquerque|Alexandria|Ammansland|Atkins\ Bank|Awiehawken|Bergen|Berlin|Beverwijck|Breuckelen|Brooklyn|Campbellton|Caswell|Chamassungh|Charleston|Cross\ Creek|Darby|Fayetteville|Finlandia|Jackson|Jersey\ City|Kingston|Kinston|Marcus\ Hook|Marne|St\.\ Charles|Weehawken)\b
```

After defining the regex you can do something like:

```
"I'm going to New York then to Berlin".scan(regex)
```

which would return:

```
# => [
    [0] "New York",
    [1] "Berlin"
]
```